# Amazon S3 lifecycle rules - common prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an Amazon S3 bucket with a structure of:

```
-Events/
--01/
---435/
----002/
------HiRes/
------Preview/
------Thumbs/
---436/
----001/
------HiRes/
------Preview/
------Thumbs/
----002/
------HiRes/
------Preview/
------Thumbs/
.
.
.and so on
```

I only want to archive the objects that are in HiRes.
Is it a matter of updating my lifecycle prefix to 'HiRes'?

The complete prefix of the "folder" I want to lifecycle is:

```
<bucketName>/Events/01/435/002/HiRes/
```

Comment: just want to confirm the complete prefix is something like this 436/001/HiRes/Preview/humbs/ right?

Comment: The complete prefix would be:  Events/01/435/002/HiRes/

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a matter of updating my lifecycle prefix to 'HiRes'

No, you should mention the entire prefix whenever the prefix for `HiRes` changes ( in the case of 435 and 436). a rule applies to all objects that share the same prefix.
[for example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-configuration-examples.html#lifecycle-config-conceptual-ex4) `01/435/002/HiRes/` or `01/436/001/HiRes/` or `01/436/002/HiRes/`

My suggestions would be to create a common prefix for your HiRes and structure would be something like `common-for-HiRes/1, common-for-HiRes/2` and then apply a common lifecycle rule for `common-for-Hires/` prefix

For Lifecycle action to a subset of objects based on different key name prefixes [see this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intro-lifecycle-rules.html)

UPDATE (based on comments) :-

if you cant change your directory structure, the try using tags or a combination of filter and tags whichever suits your case, [example for above](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intro-lifecycle-rules.html)

Comment: Gotcha.  That makes sense.  Doesn't work for me as can't go and change our directory structure.  Guess I'll revert to tagging.

Comment: if this helped,an upvote/ acceptance would help others in the future with similar problem, i will update the answer to include tagging option.